# find('threaded') for post versions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm building an application that allows the upload of multiple versions.  Is tree behavior the best way to manage that?

```
$allAssets = $this->Asset->find('threaded',  array('order' => array('id' => 'desc')));
    foreach ($allAssets as $asset):
        echo $asset['children'][0]['Asset']['value']; 
    endforeach;
```

The goal is to get the value of the most recent version of each asset.  How do I do that if there are no children?  Is there a better way to pull out a nested array for the asset versions?

Comment: I can't see any relation between "multiple versions" and the tree behavior - can you explain?

Comment: Essentially I need

     `Array
 asset1
  Version2
  Version1
 asset2
  Version1
 asset3
  Version3
  Version2
  Version1`
 
Whats the best way to set up my db and php to get this?  Do I need a tree? I'd like to keep the array as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the containable behavior

Assuming you have the following setup in your Asset model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'ParentAsset' => array(
        'className' => 'Asset',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
)

public $hasMany = array(
    'ChildAsset' => array(
        'className' => 'Asset',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => 'created ASC'
    )
);
```

you would then load the containable behavior in your AssetsController like this

```
$this->Asset->Behaviors->load('Containable',array('autoFields' => false));
```

And then perform your find like this

```
$this->Asset->find('all',  array(
    'order' => array (
        'id' => 'desc'
        ),
    'contain' => array(
        'ChildAsset' => array(
            'fields' => 'ChildAsset.value',
            'order' => 'ChildAsset.created asc'
    )
    )
);
```

This find method should return an array in the format of

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Asset' => array(
            'name' => 'assetVersion1',
            'id' => '1234'
        ),
        'ChildAsset' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'assetVersion2',
                'id' => '2222',
                'parent_id' => '1234',
                'created' => '2013-06-10 12:00:00'
            )
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'assetVersion3',
                'id' => '3333'
                'parent_id' => '1234'
                'created' => '2013-06-10 12:30:00'
            )
        )
```

Comment: the fields parameter in the contain can be left out to return all fields for ChildAsset. Also may have to play around with a conditions paramter in the contain array of the find add something like 'conditions' => array('ChildAsset.parent_id = Asset.id) or something like that... you'll have to play around with some params to get results you want.

Comment: One more thing, you could give your "parent" asset a parent_id of itself and then you should get everything, parents and children to come out in the ChildAsset nested array.

Comment: the issue is that all the versions aren't returned as 1 level deep array.  I just want to be able to sort by the ID and display the data for the highest level of each asset #.  Is there a better way to set up my database so I don't have to deal with the whole children/no children issue?

Comment: Not sure I follow... Your question asked about using child and pulling nested array. You want to sort by id or but then want most recent version? Can you show example of how you want array data to look and your table setup? Sounds like you could handle by having proper fields and sorting though normal find but you need to provide more context

Comment: Why not have a version column in your table. Then turn off any isunique validation on your asset name column then you could have asset1|version1, asset1|version2, etc...

Comment: Also if you want all values returned sorted by id with no children the you probably shloudnt use a find 'threaded', just use find 'all' and sort by asset name and id